# Angular2 + ADFS - Authenticating multiple service providers using different protocols

Tags: angular, jwt, saml-2.0, adfs, oauth-2.0

We are developing an **Angular2** single page application that accesses data from multiple service providers, we are using **OAuth2** to login users into our application and make secure calls on the users behalf to the service providers, our Identity provider is **ADFS**.

We can successfully generate **JWTs** from **ADFS** in our angular application and send them to service providers, but our problem is that some providers does not support **OAuth2**, and uses **SAML** instead.

What is the most proper way to generate both **SAML** assertions and **JWTs** in our angular SPA from **ADFS** if possible? or is there a more proper solution to implement?

Comment: Did you ever got an answer to this or were you able to solve it at least?